# Javascript Loop and Access Nested Object and Create Select Dropdown and Lists of Objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object, select, nested-loops

I have this javascript object `data` coming through. I want to create a select dropdown for "Object One" and "Object Two" as well as display the lists on the DOM like so: VW, Red, GTI, 2018 and so forth and group them under "Object One" or "Object Two" so it can be displayed accordingly by the select dropdown.

However, I'm just having a hard time looping and accessing them because of the recursion. I'm pretty new Javascript.

```
var data =
{
    "object": {"object": "sometext"},
    "group": {
        "Object One": {
            "VW": {            
              "color":"red",
              "model":"GTI",
              "year":"2018"
            },
            "Audi": {
                "color":"black",
                "model":"Q5",
                "year":"2017"
            }
        },
        "Object Two": {
            "Toyota": {
                "color":"silver",
                "model":"Fit",
                "year":"2017"
            },
            "Nissan": {
                "color":"Red",
                "model":"Cube",
                "year":"2018"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
Output should be:
[Object One] -- Shows the lists below accordingly

//Lists for Object One//
VW   red    GTI    2018
Audi black  Q5     2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. Please clear the code a litter bit.

```js
const data =
{
    "object": {"object": "sometext"},
    "group": {
        "Object One": {
            "VW": {            
              "color":"red",
              "model":"GTI",
              "year":"2018"
            },
            "Audi": {
                "color":"black",
                "model":"Q5",
                "year":"2017"
            }
        },
        "Object Two": {
            "Toyota": {
                "color":"silver",
                "model":"Fit",
                "year":"2017"
            },
            "Nissan": {
                "color":"Red",
                "model":"Cube",
                "year":"2018"
            }
        }
    }
};

function transferData(data) {
  let string = '';
  Object.keys(data.group).forEach(groupName => {
    string += `[${groupName}] -- Shows the lists below accordingly\n`;
    Object.keys(data.group[groupName]).forEach(brand => {
      string += `${brand}  ${data.group[groupName][brand].color}  ${data.group[groupName][brand].model}  ${data.group[groupName][brand].year} \n`
    });
  });
  return string;
}

console.log(transferData(data));
```

Comment: Keven, thank you so much for your help! This did clear up lot of my issues. If you don't mind, can I ask you one more question? Is it possible to access "Object One" from the second Object.keys function? Let say, I wanted to add "Object One" to each list.  

Object One VW  red  GTI  2018  

Object One Audi  black  Q5  2017  

Object Two Toyota  silver  Fit  2017 and so on...  
I'm new to SO and I have no idea how to format this comment! Sorry!

Comment: You are welcome. It is possible. You can just use groupName variable to reference it. Change it to    string += `${groupName}  ${brand}  ${data.group[groupName][brand].color}  ${data.group[groupName][brand].model}  ${data.group[groupName][brand].year} \n`